# How to keep a float within certain boundaries (say, a section)? (\FloatBarrier doesn’t seem to help because of a bug)

Tags: floats, sectioning, positioning, placeins

As far as I know, the canonical way to keep floats from appearing above or below a certain point is the command `\FloatBarrier` from the package `placeins`. However, it doesn’t seem to work in the below example: Table 1 appears *above* the last paragraph of the previous section, even though there is a `\FloatBarrier` right before `\section{Section~B}`. In this case I would like the table to be placed at the bottom of page 2, within section B.

[image: The float is incorrectly positioned]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section~A}

\lipsum[1-5]

This is the last paragraph of section~A.% And now it is long enough to take a little more vertical space.

\FloatBarrier
\section{Section~B}

This is the first paragraph of section~B.

\begin{table}
    \caption{This table belongs in section~B}%
    \label{tab:mytable}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        a & b\\
        c & d
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

This is the second paragraph of section~B, look at table~\ref{tab:mytable}.

\end{document}
```

However, if I remove the `%` from `This is the last paragraph of section~A.% And now it is long enough to take a little more vertical space.`, it typesets correctly:

[image: The float is correctly positioned]

(*Updated*)
I re-read `placeins`’s documentation, and found this paragrah:

> There is a problem with LaTeX’s “`\suppressfloats`” being out of step with the page breaking (see usenet msg `<yfi656pbsn0.fsf@triumf.ca>` and thread) which sometimes allows a float to go above a “`\FloatBarrier`” placed near the top of a page. Maybe placeins will fix it sometime later.

So it seems to be a bug in LaTeX. Now my question is this: how does one work around this bug? (The best solution would be to fix LaTeX, but this is too big for me and I have to submit my PhD thesis in 43 days… )

Comment: `\usepackage{flafter}`

Comment: You do not need at all a  float barrier, `\begin{table}[b]`  in the same page of `\section`   is more than enough to prevent place this float of and next floats before the section title, but well, `flafter` does that automatically, so ...

Comment: Actually, by the time \FloatBarrier is processed, the float has been moved from the \@deferlist to the \@toplist; it is effectively already on the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you! `flafter` is brilliant. If you will, repost this as an answer so I can mark this question as answered :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\usepackage{flafter}` (suggested by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) in a comment) does not directly solve the problem *as stated*, but does solve the root problem I was trying to solve using `\FloatBarrier`, namely how to ensure floats not typeset above where they are defined.